# ImportXML data by excluding fields in Google Sheet

Tags: google-sheets-formula

I need to import only the field highlighted in the image, but as it doesn't have a specific class in the code, I can't.

Can someone help me?

https://futebolnatv.com.br/

I try this  but this Import information I don't need. I only need the text **that is in quotes**

```
=importxml("http://www.futebolnatv.com.br/jogos-hoje/"; "//table[1]/tbody/tr/td/div[2]"),
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Here you go. `=index(importxml("http://www.futebolnatv.com.br/jogos-hoje/", "//table[1]/tbody/tr/td/div[2]"),1,3)`

Answer (score 1):

Try

```
=index(importxml(url,"//div[@class='col-md-12']"),2,3)
```

or

```
=query(importxml(url,"//div[@class='col-md-12']"),"select Col3 limit 1")
```

or, if you want both teams Dorados and Leones Negros

```
=query(importxml(url,"//div[@class='col-md-12']"),"select Col3 limit 2")
```